# Saying |ameen" when is it appropriate to respond with the word "Ameen"

Tags: sunnah

I see many people responding with this word on social networks for a simple postings such as Hadith, or a parable, or just a greeting for Eid or Ramadan etc,
should it be pronounced on a network, as it is not a live gathering.
eg:  I posted "Ramadan Kareem on Facebook, and 20 responses appeared in the comments!
I am confused, because this is not a Duaa in live gathering!

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to take our [tour], check our [help] and [meta] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 2):

Ameen or aameen آمِين means اللهم استجب May Allah accept or answer (our dua' اللهم استجب دعاءنا).

Saying/posting ameen is only allowed in two situations according to [this Article](http://www.shankeety.net/Alfajr01Beta/index.php?module=Publisher&section=Topics&action=ViewTopic&topicId=226) of Sheikh Shanqeety which comments [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/100) of Jami' at-Tirmidhi and includes fatwas on the purpose of that hadith:

- in the prayer for example: when finishing the recitation of [al-fatiha](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/82).
- and as a kind of response or reaction if one hears/reads an allowed dua', so once you hear/read somebody making dua' you are allowed (asked) to say ameen, but not for any dua' as an example: If somebody is making dua' asking Allah to cause pain to a Muslim or asking Allah for something which is not allowed, one shouldn't say ameen.

These are the only two reasons or situations saying ameen is allowed or legislated.

So if anybody posted ameen in such a situation as described in your post you should explain to him, that this isn't allowed or at least unlawful and he/she should rather use thanks/JazakaALlah khayran etc. instead of ameen.

And Allah knows best!